# Hibernate : How to get last n rows in spring boot JpaRepository?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Iam working with spring boot and jpa repository I want get the last 2 records from database using hql query.
I have writen the follwoing query but its not working.

```
@Query("select news from(select news from NewsDTO news order by news.newsId desc limit 2) sub order by news.newsId asc")
```

It is throwing the folloing exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 17 [select news from(select news from com.mer.aigs.dto.news.NewsDTO news order by news.newsId desc limit 2) sub order by news.newsId asc]
```

Comment: Not working means whether it is giving wrong result or it is not running at all??

Comment: You mean the "query" that is invalid JPQL? Wonder what "not working" means ...

Comment: Its is giving error while running the project

Answer (score 2):

JPQL doesn't support `LIMIT` clause natively. With Spring Data JPA, however, you can use 
combination of `ORDER BY .. DESC` and `Pageable` to achieve what you intend to. Refer this for detailed information https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/pagination.html

Answer (score 1):

`limit` keyword is not supported by hql (it's even different across different databases). You need to create a `Query` using entity manager and specify the maximal size:

```
em.createQuery("your query").setMaxResults(2).getResultList()
```

assuming you have entity manager injected:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em
```

This solution performs better than using `Pageable`.

Comment: Sorry but he is using Spring Data so doesn't need to use the Entity manager directly.

Comment: Andronicus thanks from your answer but iam using Jparepostory how can I use createQuery of EntityManager here???

Comment: @Alan Hay yes, but he already has the query in jpql. @Merwais Muafaq - the answer is written, you have to `@Autowire` it...

Comment: Did that resolve your problem? If yes, then consider upvoting / marking as correct, if not - continue discussion.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Kedar you cannot use `LIMIT` inside your JPQL query due to the database-specific nature. Therefore you need to use a `NATIVE QUERY` and replace the physical table name and column name for `NewsDTO` and `newsId`:

```
@Query(value = "select news from(select news from *NewsDTO* news order by *newsId* desc limit 2) sub order by *newsId* asc", nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, where `created` is the timestamp column in the table:

```js
repository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 2, Sort.by("created").descending())))
```

In my case, I wanted the result sorted by the `created` column.

Hope this helps someone.